# How do checkbox and href in the same line? Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="text-left">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox">Zapamiętaj mnie.
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="text-right">
        <a href="#">Przypomnij hasło</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do it in the same line?

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Were you able to fix this with one of the answers below?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the form-group to be a flex-container, or set the items as inline elements.

You can also use the `form-inline` class provided by [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#inline-forms), you need to create a container for all the input elements and labels (a `form` tag would be best) and just add the class to it.

Quoting Bootstrap:

> Use the `.form-inline` class to display a series of labels, form
>   controls, and buttons on a single horizontal row. Form controls within
>   inline forms vary slightly from their default states.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Making the form-group a flex-container -->
<div class="form-group d-flex">
  <div class="text-left">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
       <input type="checkbox">Zapamiętaj mnie.
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="text-right">
    <a href="#">Przypomnij hasło</a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Adding form-inline to a form container -->
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="text-left">
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
       <input type="checkbox">Zapamiętaj mnie.
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="text-right">
      <a href="#">Przypomnij hasło</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="float-left">
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox">Zapamiętaj mnie.
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="float-right">
            <a href="#">Przypomnij hasło</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The `float-*` classes are not really doing anything in this case; if you are using flex utilities (`d-flex`) it just better to stick with flex, using classes like `align-items-*` and `justify-content-*` to adjust the elements inside the container; floats, IMHO, should not be used to layout content anymore

Answer (score 0):

add row and col classes

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col text-left">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox">Zapamiętaj mnie.
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-right">
        <a href="#">Przypomnij hasło</a>
    </div>
</div>
```